# How to find lowest number using criteria from 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my situation I have a data set that contains 2 columns I am interested in querying, along with a target value I need to accommodate. The target value is 593.63 which will be on another worksheet. That number will not have an exact match in column V, so I am using a MIN IF combined function to find the closest number just over that number. the query looks as such

```
=VALUE(MIN(IF(Table3[Total Target Force]>'Spring Calculator'!K25,Table3[Total Target Force])))
```

Table3[Total Target Force] = The column in which the value I need to return in another cell resides

'Spring Calculator'! = The worksheet that contains the target value in the cell K25 (593.63)***

My question is how to add a second criteria to this using the min function again. I have a column called "Spring Count" in which there are another set of numbers. I would like to only find the closest Total Target Force where the Spring Count is the lowest number it can be. This formula will be variable, so I can't say something like =MIN[Spring Count], it needs to be tied in with my current formula, finding the closest number to the target, but also considering the lowest number in the "Spring Count" column.

In my ideal situation my goal is to find the closest number to the target in my data set from the total target force column, but only if the number in the spring count column is the lowest in the initial return.

If more information is required I am happy to provide any that is needed. I've been racking my brain for days on this and can't figure it out.

[image]

Comment: So, given these values: Target Force of 600 with a Spring Count of 2 versus Target Force of 650 with a Spring Count of 1, then which Target Force would you want? 600 or 650?

Comment: 650 with a spring count of 1, The Spring count takes priority.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicated values in your dataset - e.g. if the target value were 601.33 then would you be indifferent between rows 2 & 3? - if not then your screenshot is incomplete (i.e. you want lowest spring value, range valid=TRUE, target force just > 593.63 and possibly another condition to distinguish between duplicates)

Comment: I would be indifferent on those rows. The important thing is the spring count. If I had 2 values come back that were identical but had the lowest spring count that would be fine. It wouldn't matter which one it picked. I will be cleaning up dupes after I get this part figured out. A problem would be if I returned a value that had a higher spring count. Ideally I need closest to the target value, regardless of dupes, just with the lowest spring count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your actual data, which was over-simplified in your screenshot, you can use this [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) - in cell `AC1` in the screenshot:

```
=AA1+AGGREGATE(15,6,POWER(10,LOG10((U2:U43894=TRUE)*((V2:V43894-AA1)>0)*(V2:V43894-AA1)*(W2:W43894=AGGREGATE(15,6,POWER(10,LOG10((U2:U43894=TRUE)*((V2:V43894-AA1)>0)*(W2:W43894))),1)))),1)
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give this a shot and let you know the results. Much appreciated

Comment: So I was able to get this to work recreating the data set you have in your screen shot. I did the non MINIF option since I do no have that available to me. Once I tried applying this to my larger data set however, It results in a #NUM! error. I've checked formatting and everything matches in my sample to the large data set. My data set ranges from row 2 through 43894, the "Range Valid" column can also have FALSE as a value in it. Those are the only differences I see. I've also tried running this against only values instead of cells containing formulas and I am getting the same error.

Comment: If you post a sample of your actual data in Excel online, and then post a like to it here I can have a look at it

Comment: Apologies, I posted the wrong link. I will correct and get back to you

Comment: I can't download it either - can you post a link (maybe with another cloud-service provider) such that I _can_ download the file?

Comment: Will this work for you? https://www.dropbox.com/t/u3Z2WLYbZzc7k4XT

Comment: Ok, that shows that your original screenshot over-simplified your situation - I've edited my answer to include a revised (almost twice-as-long) formula.

Comment: Thanks so much, that seems to have done it. My apologies for not including enough info from the start. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without helper columns by using a boolean XLOOKUP formula. Likely the same for INDEX/MATCH, but that seems more complicated.

Cell F2 formula:

```
    =XLOOKUP(1,($B:$B >= $F$1)*($C:$C = MINIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,">="&$F$1)),$B:$B)
```

Parts:

($B:$B >= $F$1) --> finding which rows in array meet or exceed your target value

$C:$C = MINIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,">="&$F$1) --> The MINIFS part of this section looks for the smallest number in column C where Column B value meets or exceeds the target value.

),$B:$B) --> Complete the formula and return the value in Column B which validates as true for the other statements in the formula.

[image]

Comment: This looks very straight forward, but unfortunately I don't have minifs, that's where I was getting hung up.